# Summing a tuple in a list, in python

Tags: list, python-2.7, tuples

I know there must be a quick way to do this, but can't seem to find it.
I need to find a way to add the items in a tuple. i was hoping for something like mytuple.sum.

I have a list of tuples like mylist= [(1,3,5,3),(1,5,5,5),....,(1,3,2,1),(1,1,1,2)]

and need to be able to call on it similarly to mylist[0].sum

Thanks!

Comment: `map(sum, zip(*mylist))`?

Comment: thanks, but it returns TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

Comment: Any chance that you've assigned an integer to the name `sum` (or `zip`, but that seems less likely)? That's a bad idea, as it shadows the built-in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you want, but it's probably one of

```
sum(mylist[0])
```

or

```
sum(sum(x) for x in mylist)
```

or

```
map(sum, mylist)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, the fist one looks perfect, but when I try any of them i get TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Not from my code, you're not. It's coming from somewhere else. Check your  parens.

Comment: >> mylist= [(1,3,5,3),(1,5,5,5),(1,3,2,1),(1,1,1,2)]; sum(mylist[0])    #->    12

Comment: Cancel that, it works, thanks! (I had tried Julian Berger's option so sum was = 0)